# Stating conditions in an array filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this line of code right here:

```
var selectionItems = children.filter(function (el) { return el instanceof Path; });
```

> It's supposed to ''clone'' the children array into the selectionItems
>   variable whilst excluding all items that are not ''Paths''.

- I have trouble putting this together. I did not write this piece of
  code so I didn't understand yet *how* I am supposed to declare a
  condition to base my filtering on.
- I would like to have more conditions to base my filtering on.

How would I include, **e.g** only items that are Paths or Rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have trouble putting this together. I did not write this piece of
>   code so I didn't understand yet how I am supposed to declare a
>   condition to base my filtering on.

This is basically how `filter` works:

```
function filter(f, xs) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i=0; i<xs.length; i++) {
    if (f(xs[i], i)) {
      res.push(xs[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

`filter` is a higher-order function; it takes a predicate that's checked in the `if` statement to decide whether to add the element to the results or not.

> I would like to have more conditions to base my filtering on.

Think of how you'd do it in an `if` statement, you'd use the `&&` or `||` operators. Same with `filter`:

```
return el instanceof Path || el instanceof Rectangle;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use logical or operator, like this

```
children.filter(function(el) {
    return el instanceof Path || el instanceof Rectangle;
});
```

Now, this will pick all the elements if they are of type `Path` or `Rectangle`.

You can return any valid JavaScript expression. Internally the Truthiness of the expression will be determined by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, it seems easy peasy, but I can't seem to get what ''command'' says to clone the array into the variable.

Comment: `filter` function will be returning a new array object. It will not make changes to the original Array object. So, its kind of making a clone without the items which you don't want.